# Create specific string in php

Tags: php

i have a simple task to do but i can't find a function to help me.

at the moment i have a db cell set to a number going from 1 to 10. what i would like to do is read this number and create a string of zeros long as the number i read.

example:

- db value = 3
- string must then be = 000
- db value = n
- string must be n zeros

how can i do this? any ideas what php function i could use to create this. looking for a solution which is more elegant than:

```
if ($dbvalue==1) { $string = "0"; } else if ($dbvalue==2) { $string = "00"; } ...
```

thank you all
Simone

Comment: Have you thought about a `for` loop?

Comment: you could use php str_pad function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`str_repeat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
echo str_repeat('0', $number)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = str_repeat('0', $dbvalue);
```